# I want four blue boxes, one beside the next. They need to have text in them

Tags: html, css, wordpress, layout

This clearly is or should be an absurd question. Developing some web content within the framework of a larger site (wordpress), I am working on a certain 'look' for navigation. That look is large blue squares at the bottom of each page's content, that sit side-by-side, each containing the link text and where the text and box as an entity all can be clicked.

Ideally for responsiveness, these boxes will roll over to a new line and form multiple button rows when the screen space narrows.

Performing this miracle is trivial in anything but CSS, which I am starting to compare to bathing cats. It seems to have every intention of doing exactly not the thing I want it to do. There is no point showing the countless different code snippets that did not achieve this goal, you'll have seen them all already. I need to understand:

a) how and what kind of box should contain the text (span, div, frame etc.)

b) how to align the text in that box in the bottom right, allowing for text wrapping as necessary

c) how to arrange the boxes with respect to each other and the page

c.i) the boxes need a small gap between each other, the same gap either horizontal or vertical depending on how they stack/wrap.

c.ii) the boxes need to be aligned left and the left edge of the first box align with the left edge of the preceding text block.

c.iii) there needs to be a consistent gap between the bottom of the preceding text and the top of the first box.

Ideally you could provide the simple code required to do the job with some explanation of how it works.

**Edit: Resolved**

The fact this is in Wordpress is key, and specifically that Wordpress text editor is being used to encode this. The Wordpress text editor does not act as a code editor and does not leave the content unmolested. As such, whitespace in the code editor is interpreted to html tags that ruin the raw intent of the code.

Comment: Down-voting and voting for closure anonymously. I thought this was frowned upon in the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: Both can be anonymous. If the closer doesn't wish to leave a comment that's their right. As it stands, the question *should* be closed as **too broad** and, in my opinion, shows no research effort and thus probably deserved a downvote too.

Comment: @Paulie_D the question is not even remotely too broad, it is as specific a request as can be. The question describes the research and attempts to solve the problem, albeit in the general case. Additional information on assorted research has the real threat of clouding and confusing the core issue more than helping. The request is still not resolved, as the answers present only work in the most vanilla of cases. What might be against the spirit of SO is the tone of frustration and contempt towards the technology, but only by discussing that problem can it be resolved.

Comment: And they matter, so lets encourage discussion.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a discussion site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can create a div as a parent container, with each box as a div within. Using a span, you can contain the text within each box. When you make the box class have a position of "relative," you can then control the position of the contained span absolutely. See the example below:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">
    <span class="box-text">testing</span>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <span class="box-text">testing</span>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <span class="box-text">testing</span>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <span class="box-text">testing</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #336699;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em;
}

.box-text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvGKVK

Comment: Instructions understood perfectly (I laughed at the edit). I can see that in the result you have come up with it works perfectly, but in the site I'm working on this for me gives a reasonably similar result as I've had before. Each blue box is offset down vertically approximately one line from the box preceding it.

Comment: haha, I was only giving three boxes at first. Can you share the HTML/CSS of the container that these boxes will be in?

Comment: Honestly I don't know if I can. Not for permission, but just for the cascade probably going very deep into the bowels of Wordpress and the template. I think I just need some pointers on what I should be looking for in say 'Inspect Element' in Chrome. Also it looks like I'll need to get an answer relatively quickly before some chap decides to down-vote this to oblivion. This genuine question is costing real points here..!

Comment: You can try to "inspect element" and disable styles that are being applied or inherited by your div elements (boxes). I would do this until you achieve your desired effect. If the page is live, I can take a look as well.

Comment: Cheers for the offer @sd84, I think I might be fighting some inbuilt wordpress horror based on my look at the inspector. The code I'm writing seems to be having another level of interpretation laid upon it and <br> elements added unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="bluebox">
  <span class="text">Text</span>
</div>
<div class="bluebox">
  <span class="text">Text</span>
</div><div class="bluebox">
  <span class="text">Text</span>
</div><div class="bluebox">
  <span class="text">Text</span>
</div><div class="bluebox">
  <span class="text">Text</span>

.bluebox {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

.text {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  width:100%;
  color:white;
  text-align:right;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYoObJ

Comment: I agree that display: inline-block; is the better idea for the adjacent boxes.

Comment: This is a correct answer however the other answer came first and discussion in the other answer led to finding the ultimate resolution.